# Find Closest 1D array in 2D numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the best match of a 1D array from a 2D array.

```
arr1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])

arr2 = np.array([1.1, 1.1, 1.1])
```

how can I get it to return the best match i.e. row 0 preferably as the index of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "closest" means smallest absolute difference to, try something like:

```
idx = np.abs(arr1 - arr2).sum(axis=1).argmin()  # 0
```

Absolute difference [np.absolute](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html#numpy-absolute):

```
np.abs(arr1 - arr2)
```

```
[[0.1 0.1 0.1]
 [0.9 0.9 0.9]]
```

Row-wise total difference [sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html#numpy-ndarray-sum):

```
np.abs(arr1 - arr2).sum(axis=1)
```

```
[0.3 2.7]
```

Min-Index [argmin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmin.html#numpy-ndarray-argmin):

```
np.abs(arr1 - arr2).sum(axis=1).argmin()
```

```
0
```

Comment: How would you extend this to x closest? (Like KNN?)